# How to run JMeter through CMD from jdk/bin directory?

Tags: java, java-8, jmeter

I want to run JMeter test plans from a UNIX server where env variables for java is not set. Its a test server and I dont have access to set that. We have different JDK versions and all are sitting in directories. I need to run my JMeter TestPlans on this server. I went to JDK /bin folder and tired to execute the below command

```
$ {jmeter-path}/bin/jmeter -nt testplan.jmx -l testresult.jtl
```

but this says

```
./bin/java: not found
```

But if I do simple java -version it shows the version result.Is that something that JMeter needs specifically the java env variable set or it wont run ? I dont have permission to set and I want to run the testplan using the JDK/JRE from its directories. A help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I think I could work around this by editing the jmeter script file as suggested in the one of the comments. Since my requirement was running the JMeter from a specific server, I could achieve this by editing the JAVA_HOME variable value in the script.

Comment: jmeter is usally a jar file.

Comment: If you're in the jdk/bin directory and the error message is "./bin/java: not found", then obviously it's looking for java in the non-existent `jdk/bin/bin` directory. Try going one level up.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter looks for `java` executable in system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so you have 2 options:

1. Add `bin` folder of your JDK or JRE to PATH, something like:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/location/of/your/jbk/bin && export PATH && {jmeter-path}/bin/jmeter -nt testplan.jmx -l testresult.jtl
   ```
2. Or if you have `java` in PATH [just run `ApacheJMeter.jar` like](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal):

   ```
   java -jar {jmeter-path}/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```
3. You might also want to use [`jmeter.sh`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/jmeter.sh) wrapper script instead of `jmeter`, it has some logic regarding `java` binary location

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Answer (score 1):

The **official** JMeter Getting Started documentation [says this](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install):

> To install a release build, simply unzip the zip/tar file into the directory where you want JMeter to be installed. Provided that you have a JRE/JDK correctly installed and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set, there is nothing more for you to do.

Based on the symptoms that you reported, I think that you have not set `JAVA_HOME` correctly.  It *should* be set to an absolute path to your Java installation's top directory.

Comment: I dont have permission to set the PATH. Its a test server and we have different JDK versions in the folders so that people can use as per requirements. Is there anyway I can run this JMeter from JDK/bin folder ? I tried and I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: 1) I didn't say `PATH`.  I said `JAVA_HOME`. 2)  If you cannot set `JAVA_HOME` either, then take a copy of the `jmeter` script, read it to find the places where it invokes `java`, and modify them to use an absolute path for the version of the `java` command you want to use.

Comment: P.S.  In Linux there is nothing to stop you from setting an environment variable in your command shell.  (Unless you are running in a "restricted shell" jail of some sort.  If that is the case, talk you your system administrators about how to deal with this problem.)